# read command with ??? input

Tags: bash, osx, read

Why when reading input with `read`, and the input is `???` the result is `bin src`?

```
$ read
???
$ echo $REPLY
bin src
```

Running `bash` on macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data held in the variable `REPLY` is still `???`, but the result from using the variable *unquoted* with `echo`, like you are doing, is the same as doing

```
echo ???
```

You need to double quote all variable expansions.

When you leave a variable expansion unquoted, two things happens:

1. The value of the variable is *split* into multiple words.  The splitting happens wherever a character is the same as one of the characters in `$IFS` (a  space, tab and a newline by default).  In your case, the result of the splitting is the same as before the splitting (the single word `???`) if the value of `$IFS` is not modified.
2. Each generated word undergoes *filename generation*, or "filename globbing".  That means that if a word is a globbing pattern, which `???` is, any filenames matching that pattern will replace the pattern.  The pattern `???` matches any three character long filename and you obviously have two of those in your current working directory.

Neither of these things happens if the variable expansion is double-quoted.

Example, recreating your issue and solving it:

```
$ ls
X11R6   games   lib     libexec mdec    ports   share   xobj
bin     include libdata local   obj     sbin    src
$ read
???
$ echo $REPLY
bin lib obj src
$ echo ???
bin lib obj src
$ echo "$REPLY"
???
```

Another example in the same directory as above, showing that the string that I input is split into two words (`???` and `s*`) and that these then gets used as filename globbing patterns:

```
$ read
??? s*
$ echo $REPLY
bin lib obj src sbin share src
$ echo "$REPLY"
??? s*
```

Notice that `src` gets outputted twice as it matches both `???` and `s*`.

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Short summary of the above questions and answers:  *Always* double quote *all* expansions, unless you know exactly which ones don't need it or if you actually want to invoke splitting and globbing.